# WP8 Datetime.UtcNow returns a time which differs by few seconds

Tags: c#, datetime, windows-phone-8, utc

I am using UTC seconds timestamp to sync to the servers.. When device timestamp is greater, it pushes data to the server, when server timestamp is greater, it pulls from the server.

Every time data is changed, the timestamp in the phone is updated to the latest time. I use the following functions to convert date to seconds

```
    long seconds = FromDateToSeconds(DateTime.UtcNow);

    public long FromDateToSeconds(DateTime date)
    {
        var epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

        return Convert.ToInt64((date - epoch).TotalSeconds);
    }
```

When the data is sync'd, the server returns an updated timestamp which is updated in the device. When ever you change the data jus after it is synced. The FromDatetoSeconds functions returns a timestamp which is lesser than the last server sync timestamp. I see a difference of 1-15seconds?

I dont understand how this is possible. Does UtcNow return the correct time? Or is it off by 10-20 secs?

Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the latency of request to server?

Comment: probably around 5 to 10 seconds when the connectivity is good.

Answer (score 0):

The clock in the phone is not synced against anything except for when the mobile operator enables synchronization (and I do not think any operator has).

This means that the clock in your phone is of a few seconds if not even minutes! The only thing you can do is to calculate time incl. the offset.

To do so, pull the current time from a time server and then calculate the difference. Add this difference to all times.